# Open a link in a new tab in GWT works but displays its content in the original tab as well

Tags: gwt, tabs, anchor

I'm using GWT 2.5.1 and can't figure out why but when openining a link in a new tab results in displaying the same content in the original (where the clicks come from) tab as well. Here is a code:

```
private void createMyloLink(String text, String targetUrl) {
        Anchor link = new Anchor(text, targetUrl);
        link.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                Window.open(link.getHref(), "_blank", "");
            }
        });
    }
```

in Firefox and Chrome it opens the link in a new tab without problem. What is weird is that when I right-click on the link and choose 'open in a new Tab', the new tab opens and its content DOES NOT flow into the tab of origin (where I clicked on the link). On the other side, if I just click on the link, the new tabs opens but its content is also injected in the origin tab. 
Any idea on how to fix the problem or to achieve the right working ? Thank you

Answer (score 4):

This is the expected behaviour of your code snippet.

```
 Anchor link = new Anchor(text, targetUrl);
```

If you click on this anchor , the `targetUrl` is opened in the current tab.

By adding the `ClickHandler` a new tab with `targetUrl` is opened.

**Solution:**

Create anchor with target "_blank" and remove the `ClickHandler`.

```
private void createMyloLink(String text, String targetUrl) {
    Anchor link = new Anchor(text, targetUrl, "_blank");
}
```

Comment: Nope. in Firefox and Chrome it opens the link in a new tab without problem. What is weird is that when I right-click on the link and choose 'open in a new Tab', the new tab opens and its content DOES NOT flow into the tab of origin (where I clicked on the link). On the other side, if I just click on the link, the new tabs opens but its content is also injected in the origin tab.

Comment: j.s is right - either use Anchor with "_blank", or a Label with a ClickHandler.